# VirtualBox on Bootcamp, where is the Host key?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp, virtualization, virtualbox

I installed VB on top of Windows, in Boot Camp.

VirtualBox has the concept of a Host key, which varies from one OS to another. It could i.e. be the right <kbd>^ Control</kbd> key.

In this context they say to i.e. go Fullscreen your press <kbd>Host</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>.

The Host Key should be shown in the Task Bar of the VM, here it shows right <kbd>^ Control</kbd>. However there is no right <kbd>^ Control</kbd> on a Mac keyboard.

I installed VirtualBox in Bootcamp. So, where is the Host key?

Already tried <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>  but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The host key is assigned to that key even though you can‘t press it on the internal keyboard of a MacBook Pro. But can‘t you just redefine it in VB?

Comment: How to redefine it?

Comment: Doesn‘t the manual explain this?

Comment: I see how to redefine the i.e. `Fullscreen` shortcut but not how to redefine the `Host` key. And when I try to do that, no matter the key I press (`ctrl`, `command `, `shift` or `alt`), it shows `Host`.

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#globalsettings seems to mention this. I can't install VB to verify this though.

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>Host</kbd> key for VirtualBox in MacOS is the <kbd>Left Command</kbd>